# What is the best thing to log for an exception when using log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

What should I be logging in my exceptions so I can all the details?

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.Error("Users.GetUser " + ex.??????);
}
```

Should I be passing just the variable `ex` or should I be doing:

```
ex.InnerException + ex.Message + ex.Source
```

Comment: That doesn't depends on what information you need?

Comment: Yes, well I want all the information regarding the exception so I can trace the error.   Is there a best practice?

Comment: How about using a overload which takes exception `Logger.Error("Users.GetUser:", ex);`

Comment: @juharr that is just with the default appeneder, the key thing to understand is there are two parts to Log4Net, Loggers (the stuff that takes information in) and Appenders (stuff that outputs the stuff that was taken in from the loggers). With the overload that takes in a exception everything you need is already "logged" however what may not be happening is everything you want is not "written out" by the appender you have configured.

Comment: You need  to log information that will help you with understanding the exception. As @ScottChamberlain pointed out in comment and answer - start with whole exception object. Note that in many cases you'd need more information about current parameters/context - see if you can guess what would you need and log it too (i.e. "Acesss denied" exception does not come with "current user name" which can vary if you use impersonation - maybe you'll want to log that: `.Error("Exception while running under user: " + Environment.UserName, ex)`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In that case I wound not do that either. I would make a variable for it and push it on to the context `using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["UserName"].Push(Environment.UserName)) { Log.Error("Some Details about the exception", ex); }` this lets you refrence the variable `%UserName` in your appender without it being tied to the message. (Just be sure your appender uses the `%UserName` variable)

Answer (score 5):

`Error` [has a overload](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ILog.Error_overload_2.html) that takes in a exception as one of the parameters. So your logger should be in the form

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.Error("Users.GetUser", ex);
}
```

It is then your responsibility to make sure your appender is also set up to record the information from the exception. If you look at their [appender examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) they have a MS SQL appeneder that puts the exception info in to its own column.

```xml
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=[database server];initial catalog=[database name];integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=[user];Password=[password]" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

Comment: In fact all methods have an overload with an exception: Debug, Info, Warn, Error, Fatal can all be used like this

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ILog.Error(string, exception)` method to log errors. This will give you all pertinent exception information - the exception type, message and stack trace will all be displayed:

```
log.Error("Construction of Foo failed due to the following exception", ex);
```

If you ever want to build a custom log entry depending on values in code, use the `ILog.*Format(string, params object[] args)` methods:

```
int i = 20; int y = 25
log.InfoFormat("The value of i is {0}, and the value of x is {1}", i, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this is my global.asax:

```
  Exception lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError();
        Log.Error(lastErrorWrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are catching a general Exception then just use `.ToString()` because you don't know anything more about the exception unless you specifically write code to find out.
.ToString() will give you the stack trace allowing you to see where the problem occurred.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.Error("Users.GetUser " + ex.ToString());
}
```

If you are catching specific exception types then you way want to log certain details within that exception which you will need to diagnose a problem. Take a WebException for example. You might want to know what the content type is. This information wouldn't be available in a normal .ToString() log.

```
catch(WebException webex)
{
    Logger.Error(webex.Response.ContentType);
}
```

Basically it all depends on the exception and what you want to know.

The question you need to ask yourself is : "If an error occurs what do I need in order to diagnose the problem."